# How do I get the gmaps.js map size?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gmaps.js

I'm using gmaps.js. I'd like to get the current width and height of the map in pixels, so that I can adjust the density of points. I skimmed through the gmaps.js source, but nothing really stuck out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

width and height can be accessed independently through GMaps.el.clientWidth and GMaps.el.clientHeight.